# Screen scrape HTML head content?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am comfortable scraping HTML content by using the CSS elements as a method of identifying the section of content that I want, but I need to scrape the content of the  section of a webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0028)http://www.peoplesafe.co.uk/ -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>PeopleSafe</title>
    <link href="css/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link href="http://www.peoplesafe.co.uk/styles/default/screen_ie6.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" href="http://www.peoplesafe.co.uk/styles/default/favicon.ico" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabpane.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="css/tab.webfx.css?v=2" />


    <meta http-equiv="Author" content="Rare Creative Group" />
    <meta http-equiv="Description" content="Experts in lone worker safety" />
    <meta http-equiv="Keywords" content="lone, worker, safety" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spotlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/promo.js"></script>    

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?ile=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAA04SCF3o4CZghg6c0Qqgd-RQxzn3bXKr_TQ6C8c2CiIf8-vjJhBS3endtVbbJ1vftXL4Wbb2PwuJ8ag" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
function load()
{
    // required for original Peoplesafe layout:
    start();

    if ( GBrowserIsCompatible() )
    {
        // codice setcenter:
        var map = new GMap2( document.getElementById( "map" ) );

        var customUI = map.getDefaultUI();
        // Remove MapType.G_HYBRID_MAP
        //customUI.maptypes.hybrid = false;
        map.setUI(customUI);
        //map.addControl( new GSmallMapControl() );
        //map.addControl( new GMapTypeControl() );

        map.setCenter( new GLatLng( 51.612308, -1.239453 ), 11 );

        // Crea un nuovo marker nel punto specificato con una descrizione HTML associata:
        function createMarker( point, description, primary_contact_id )
        {
            //var icon = new GIcon();
            ////icon.shadow = "/images/nuvola.png";
            //icon.iconSize = new GSize(87, 38);
            ////icon.shadowSize = new GSize(107, 38);
            //icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
            //icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
            //icon.image = "/img/.";
```

I need to somehow parse the latitude and longitude from this line:

```
map.setCenter( new GLatLng( 51.612308, -1.239453 ), 11 );
```

So in one column of my table I would like the first part:

```
51.612308
```

and in a second column I would like the second part:

```
-1.239453
```

Is this possible without the availability of CSS selectors?

**Edit**

Thanks for the help so far, very much appreiated!

The initial problem was to do with a redirect as soon as you log in to the site, I've sorted that and now when I do:

```
put page.root
```

I get the full source of the page that I expected. So now my code (after logging in) is:

```
html_doc = page.root

# Find the first <script> in the head that does not have src="..."
#script = html.at_xpath('/html/head/script[not(@src)]')

# Use a regex to find the correct code parts in the JS, using named captures
parts = script.text.match(/new GLatLng\(\s*(?<lat>.+?)\s*,\s*(?<long>.+?)\s*\)/)

p parts[:lat], parts[:long]
#=> "51.612308"
#=> "-1.239453"
```

I get an error when running the above:

```
undefined local variable or method `script' for main:Object
```

Comment: Can you not just put them in with HTML? Are they static?

Comment: It's a service providers website without an API, we have permission to scrape but we can't alter the HTML code. They are the lat/long of a phone we use for our lone workers so are almost realtime.

Comment: On your hosting environment write a web-method using some server side technology asp.net, php, jsp to scrap the web-page data then extract the data from the returned html content

Comment: I have a rake task (Ruby) that opens the webpage, logs in and will eventually extract the data - I don't know how to extract the exact data I need though. I've done it before using CSS selectors.

Comment: Your new error is because you never create a `script` variable! See my re-edited answer. (In the future, I urge you not to blindly copy/paste code given to you, but understand what it does and how it applies.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry - I definitely need to get a better understanding of exactly what's going on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution; take note that the returned parts are strings, and so you may need to call `to_f` on them to perform calculations:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
html_doc = Nokogiri.HTML(my_html)

# Find the first <script> in the head that does not have src="..."
script = html_doc.at_xpath('/html/head/script[not(@src)]')

# Use a regex to find the correct code parts in the JS, using named captures
parts = script.text.match(/new GLatLng\(\s*(?<lat>.+?)\s*,\s*(?<long>.+?)\s*\)/)

p parts[:lat], parts[:long]
#=> "51.612308"
#=> "-1.239453"
```

If you are not comfortable with that XPath expression to find the script, you could alternatively do something like:

```
script = html.css('head script').find{ |el| el['src'].nil? }
```

i.e. Find all script tags in the head, and then use a [standard Ruby method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to find the first element matching a particular criterion.

**Edit**: If you are using Mechanize, it uses Nokogiri internally to parse and process the document. You can either get the Nokogiri HTML Document object directly via the code

```
html_doc = my_mechanize_page.root
```

…or you can use the [`Mechanize::Page#at`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-at) method to call Nokogiri's own `at` internally on the page's contents.

*I personally prefer the former, as the Nokogiri Document gives you a richer set of methods than just `at`. Either would work with the above code, however.*

**Edit 2**: For example:

```
script = page.at('/html/head/script[not(@src)]')
parts = script.text.match(/new GLatLng\(\s*(?<lat>.+?)\s*,\s*(?<long>.+?)\s*\)/)
```

Comment: Using your first example I get an error. The entire script looks like this https://gist.github.com/2312571 am I missing something?

Comment: @dannymcc Yes, you are missing something. Read what the error message says. Then review line 24 of your script critically.

Comment: 'html = Nokogiri.HTML(my_html)' Line 24 confused me, should I be replacing my_html with something?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had mentioned Mechanize! My mistake. https://gist.github.com/2312571 It's failing with 'undefined method  text' I'm a little confused by the script = page.at(..) part.

Comment: @dannymcc Please edit your question with updated code and the exact error message you are getting. I assume that `script` it is failing to get the script, but I cannot be sure given your sparse details.

Comment: A gist of the exact HTML being returned would be particularly useful (sanitized, if you like, but otherwise unchanged). Try `puts page.root` to see what you get back after submitting the form.

Comment: @dannymcc Other than the fact that this page claims to be XHTML when it is in fact broken and invalid, I see no problem. It works for me when I load this page directly as an HTML document. Again, if it is not working for you, you need to provide exact details and begin your own investigations, validating assumptions. Are you _sure_ that this is the HTML page returned in your script after you submit the form?

Comment: Thanks, there was an issue with a redirect after login which I hadn't picked up on. I've updated my question, still getting an error though :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible without CSS selectors. If you can read the page into a buffer or array you can pick apart the pieces you need.

Delimiting at `(` and `)` will allow you to check for the unique string `new GLatLng`. Which you know will be the element before your lat/long. See also NitinJS's comment and this page for assistance breaking the string apart http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php